# CSS hover for another element inside the same element

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
.int_menu > li.showhide {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #F36F25;
}
.int_menu > li.showhide:hover {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #F36F25;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

which changes the background colour on hover fine, however i also have an `em` which i need to change when the above is hovered over, i tried adding `:hover` after `em`

```
.int_menu > li.showhide .icon em {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

but that didnt work and it only does the change when hovering over each `em`

how can i make all `em` elements inside `li.showhide` change on hover of `.int_menu > li.showhide:hover {`

Comment: i know its possible in CSS, im not just sure how. but yes, css please

Comment: If you need it to do something different than the parent you need to set a JavaScript trigger

Comment: @jollarvia Not for children actually, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is this. I think you were pretty close, you just have to put the child selector after the `:hover`.

CSS:

```
.int_menu > li.showhide:hover em { 
    margin-bottom: 3px; 
    display: block;
    width: 20px; 
    height: 2px; 
    background: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Or something similar